# publish app to store Google Play Console return error

Tags: flutter, google-play, publish, google-play-console, mobile-application

Google Play Console returns an error when publishing app to store, can anyone fix this error?

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dropit.corporate/com.dropit.corporate.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-h_WHPV76HfsGERQzAxywUg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.en.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.x86.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-h_WHPV76HfsGERQzAxywUg==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/lib/x86, /data/app/androidx.test.tools.crawler-h_WHPV76HfsGERQzAxywUg==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.x86.apk!/lib/x86, /data/app/com.dropit.corporate-9X2nG9BzmgLZPE-yPU1caw==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libflutter.so"

I tried to solve the problem but it not solved  with me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If it's Google Play Console issue, consider using their dedicated ticket system. By the way, please use (Markdown) formatting for code/logs you post. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for details.